# How can I update a table that is only a LEFT JOIN in my query?

Tags: php, html, css

I want to update the value of only the CHARGES in the table. And I'm having a ERROR of :

> **Notice**: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\VCCDMStry\pages\save_receipt.php on line 4
>
> **Notice**: Undefined index: charges in C:\xampp\htdocs\VCCDMStry\pages\save_receipt.php on line 5
>
> **Fatal error**: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = NULL' at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\VCCDMStry\pages\save_receipt.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\VCCDMStry\pages\save_receipt.php(8): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\VCCDMStry\pages\save_receipt.php on line 8

Here is my code for fetch:

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tenant 
            LEFT JOIN stall ON stall.stall_id = tenant.stall_id
            LEFT JOIN rent ON rent.tenant_id = tenant.tenant_id
            LEFT JOIN receipt ON receipt.tenant_id = tenant.tenant_id
            LEFT JOIN rate ON rate.rate_id = tenant.rate_id
            WHERE rent.rent_status = ? AND rate.rate_id = ?
    ";
    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(1,1));
    $fetch = $query->fetchAll();

    foreach ($fetch as $key => $value) { ?>                         
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?=$value['tenant_fname']." ".$value['tenant_mname']." ".$value['tenant_lname'];?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?=$value['stall_number'];?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?=$value['charges'];?>
        </td>
        <td class = "center" style = "text-align:center;">
            <a href = "#receipt<?php echo $value['tenant_id'];?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-outline btn-xs btn-primary"> Make Receipt
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>   
    <?php include 'receipt_modal.php';?>              
<?php }?>
```

Here is my code for the UPDATE :

```
<?php    
    include 'dbcon.php';

    $receipt_id = $_POST['id'];
    $charges = $_POST['charges'];

    $query = $conn->prepare("UPDATE receipt SET charges = ? , WHERE id = ? ");
    $query->execute(array($charges,$receipt_id));

    header ('location:elecbills.php');
?>
```

And the code of the Modal:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type = "hidden" class="form-control" name= "id"  value = "<?php echo $value['tenant_id'];?>">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">PRESENT </label>: <input class = "custom-input" id="charges" name="charges"></input> 
</div>
```

Comment: Those values doesn't existing in `$_POST`. You don't show your form tag, so we don't know if your method is GET or POST. You can try using `$_REQUEST` instead, or double-check your method.

Comment: @aynber here is my form <form  action="save_receipt.php" method="POST">

Comment: @aynber I already tried the $_REQUEST but it is still not working, and the errors are just the same,

Comment: But do you have a `id` and `charges` input fields in the form you are POSTING

Comment: Can you be sure about `$value['tenant_id']` have correct value and your update sql seems to me a bit wrong but i am not very sure about your intention maybe it should be like `... WHERE tenant_id = ?`

Comment: I would say that the `Modal` need a `<form>....</form>`

Comment: maybe he needs the `</form>` after the including modal.php

Comment: @Santa'shelper there is already a closing of the form

Comment: Can you provide some html source code from your browser `view source` only the form ?

Comment: @Santa'shelper like a inspect element? or f12?

Comment: yeap like inspect element copy the form element and inner elements here, if there are too many unnecessary elements you can get rid of them.

Comment: By the way your include line `<?php include 'receipt_modal.php';?>  ` is in `foreache` so in your html there are multi `input` which has same name `id` is this purpose ?

Comment: @Santa'shelper <div class="modal-body"> == $0 <form action="save_receipt.php" method="POST"></form>

Comment: @Santa'shelper yes sir I already included the receipt_modal.php

Comment: @Santa'shelper sir? can you give me your gmail account or fb account so that we could chat? i dont have enough reputation for chat here

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125934/questions-40090105 try here

Comment: @Santa'shelper i can see your chats in the chat room but i cant reply, there is a 20 reputation required.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125935/discussion-between-ronnel-d-and-santas-helper).

Answer (score 0):

Fatal error raised cause you have comma before 'WHERE'

```
UPDATE receipt SET charges = ? , WHERE id = ?
```